# react native how to merge two arrays with a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I have two functions and when I press each of them I create an array.

```
    this.state = {
            food:[],
            sports:[],
            interest:[],   
        } 

         _favoriteFood(foodState){
            const food = foodState
            this.setState({food:food})
            console.log(food)
            console.log(this.state.food)
          }

         _favoriteSports(SportsState){
            const sports = SportsState
            this.setState({sports:sports})
            console.log(sports)
            console.log(this.state.sports)
          }
render(){


return (
<View>
      <FavoriteFood favoriteFood={this._favoriteFood}/>
</View>
       <View>
             <FavoriteSports favoriteSports={this._favoriteSports}/>
       </View>
)}
```

So for example, I am getting arrays like `food:[pizza, hodog]` and `sports:[basketball, surfing]` when I call a method by pressing a button.

My question is when I try to merge two arrays like:

```
const interest = [...this.state.food, ...this.state.sports]
```

Its showing `undefined` because I think I am calling it before the render happens.

Should I make another method to merge arrays? 
Any advice or comments would be really helpful. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Where and when do you call the function that merges those states?

Comment: I edited my text. Please take a look Thanks!

Comment: The code and the question are very inconsistent. For example, you use 3(!) different names for a single variable: `food`, `toggle1` and `toggle1Text`.

Comment: @Finesse my mistake. I edited the code.

Comment: Still, I can't see where do you make this assignment and use it.

Comment: Also, try not to create an additional state (interest here) if you can drive it from your current state.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You problem can happen because React doesn't change the state immediately when you call `setState`, it may change the state later. If you want to access the state after React applies the change, you should use the second argument of the `setState` method:

```
_favoriteFood(food){
  this.setState({food}, () => {
    const interest = [...this.state.food, ...this.state.sports];
  });
}
```

[Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

The other solution is to use your method argument instead of reading the same value from `this.state`:

```
_favoriteFood(food){
  this.setState({food});
  const interest = [...food, ...this.state.sports];
}
```

BTW, you should not store `const interest = [...this.state.food, ...this.state.sports]` in the state, because it can be derived from the other state variables.

Comment: thank you very much it works great. In the console now I see the merged arrays.

Comment: but how would I call merged arrays inside the `render() {return()}` ?

Comment: @kirimi Inside `render` this way: `const interest = [...this.state.food, ...this.state.sports];`. The `render` method must be able to render any possible component state so make an `if` statement that renders something else when the value is undefined.

Comment: @kirimi Or add a default value for the state item. According to your question, neither `this.state.food` nor `this.state.sports` can be undefined in any moment of time (if the methods are given values).

Answer (score 5):

Push multi item in array

Merge Two Array

```
var subject1=['item1','item2']


var subject=['item3','item4','item5'];

subject1.push(...subject)

console.log(subject1);

//output

['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5']
```